# React Intl - Creating an input that needs a placeholder attribute to be translated

Tags: reactjs, formatmessage

```js
const Input = props => (
  <InputWrapper
    skew={props.skew}
  >
    <InputElement
      skew={props.skew}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      type={props.type}
    />
  </InputWrapper>
);
```

I'm trying to find an example online explaining how I use the `<FormattedMessage id="" defaultMessage="" />` component for placeholders. We have JSON files where we set the different languages for it to point to. So as an example that I have above the ID would point to the json file and then into that object to pick the right value for the language. So we'd have multiple json files for each language.

How would we go about doing this for a placeholder attribute as I need to return a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume it correctly:

- You have translations in a `JSON` file.
- The `id` specifies the translation
- You want to use the translated message as the `defaultMessage` property of a `FormattedMessage` component

If that is incorrect please comment. If it's correct i would:

- Create a function in some util file that gets me the translation
- Create a custom component that wraps the `FormattedMessage` component

In some `util.jsx` file:

```
const getTranslationFromId(id) = (id) => {
    // Get translation from JSON file here!
    const translatedMessage = ...; 

    return translatedMessage;
}
```

In `FormattedTranslatedMessage.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import {getTranslationFromId} from "../some/path/to/utils";

const FormattedTranslatedMessage = ({id, ...restProps}) => (
    <FormattedMessage defaultMessage={getTranslationFromId(id)} {...restProps} />
);

export default FormattedTranslatedMessage;
```

Please comment if my suggestions are wrong or i could improve the answer...